# Removed contacts reappear in Yahoo! Messenger (in webmail client)?

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-messenger

I've accessed Yahoo Messenger from it's web interface (within the Yahoo! webmail client) and now I see some contacts I've removed a long time ago from my list (using the Windows client).

Any idea why is this happening and how can I get rid of these contacts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, You need to delete them from "Contacts" tab in your Yahoo mail.

> 1. Check the box next to each contact that you want to delete.
> 2. The right side of the page lists several options.
> 3. Click the Delete option, and then confirm the deletion.
>
> The names are moved to your Deleted Contacts where you can restore them if you like.

See [How Do I delete a contact?](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/contacts/add/contactsadd-05.html;_ylt=AjbGd94hegWytEUYst8CWiL3UCV4).

Comment: Did that and they still appear in the messenger list with **pending add request** status.

Comment: After making logout and logging in again those contacts disappeared . Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: glad it worked, anytime!.

Comment: I have the same problem. I deleted the contacts , I have already deleted them from my address book too, but they still appear in my messenger list. I have re-installed the yahoo, tried everything. When I sign back in , everything is back as if I haven't deleted anybody. What can I do????